# How can I get the newer version of android?

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

My device (Samsung S4 mini i9195) carries a 4.2.2 version. When I ask for a software update manually, it says that the latest version is already installed. How can I force it to accept the actual latest version (4.4.2) as depicted in this [page](http://live.samsung-updates.com/index.php?device=GT-I9195)?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge you have to wait until your carrier pushes the update. Unless you are on a Google Play edition or Nexus device, your carrier reviews the updated software from the manufacturer and adds what it deems to be necessary additions, applications, etc.

Comment: Google Play edition is actually released by the manufacturer not Google. Samsung add the Touchwiz framework support for the S-View Cover, and HTC add Beats Audio, and the rest is stock!

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting update most probably because the new version of OS is not yet released for your REGION. If really want to update(not official) you can install custom ROMS. But at the end of day I would prefer you retain your present OS if its not posing problems.